# Jest Globals receive 'is not a function' error, works fine without Globals

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function `addHours` to be tested. function `addHours` calls function `getHours`:

```
function getHour(date) {
    return date.getHours();
}
```

```
function addHours(date, hrsToAdd) {
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + hrsToAdd);
    return date;
}
```

I tested `addHours` with ordinary `describe ... it ...`  and it passed:

```
describe('test add hours', () => {
    it('addHours(date, 0) should return current hour', () => {
        expect(addHours(new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'), 0)).toEqual(new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'));
    });
});
```

Now I'm trying to use Jest Globals like this, but I got error: `date.getHours is not a function`:

```
describe('test add hours', () => {
    test.each`
        func                         | parameter     | expected
        ${addHours}  | ${(new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'), 0)} | ${new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')}
    `('returns $expected when $func($paramter)', ({ func, parameter, expected }) => {
        expect(func(parameter)).toBe(expected);
    });
});
```

The error is:

```
    TypeError: date.getHours is not a function

      38 |
      39 | function addHours(date, hrsToAdd) {
    > 40 |     date.setHours(date.getHours() + hrsToAdd);
         |                        ^
      41 |     return date;
      42 | }
      43 |
```

Any idea why and how to make it work?

Comment: You're misusing comma operator. `(new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'), 0) === 0`. You don't pass multiple arguments as you expect.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma operator is misused, `(new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'), 0)` evaluates to `0`. The expression doesn't result in multiple arguments. Inside `addHours`, `date === 0` and `hrsToAdd === undefined`.

It likely should be:

```
...
${addHours}  | ${[new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'), 0]} | ${new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')}
...
```

and

```
expect(func(...parameter)).toBe(expected);
```